ubuntu 24.04, Desktop, music, downloads, pictures .. folders disappear
-so while using my ubuntu 24.04, i clicked onDesktop icon and i've got "oops something went wrong unable to find /home/Desktop please check the spelling or try again later"

i reboot the laptop and found out i cant login, Msg password incorrect, tried to reset the password in recovery mode and i succeed, ---> relogin
same behavior for other folders,
-the disk 500G exists with df-h
ls -la not showing those folders,
-find cant find the folders
editing ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs  , found out the paths are not existing

"XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
" i tried to rewrite the paths and reboot but the file return to None values like is the recent past "

i dont have a restore plan
i have sensitive data they can't be lost


This sounds like the hard drive or another hardware component is failing.

the laptop is brand new its i7 12th G 30G ram, it made alot of works with 0 hardware failure, this is the new bug and i couldnt find a solution on network bizarre

This question is similar to: Home directories turned into symbolic links without telling me the reason. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You don't actually have sensitive that can't be lost, if you don't have backups. You just have sensitive data that you hope doesn't get lost.
